# The lambda function result is mathematically wrong

Tags: python, function, math, lambda

why when i write -2 ** 2 in python the result is  -4 but my lambda function is returning 4 anyone could explain why this is happening

[image: Code result]

```
two = lambda: 2
sqr = lambda x: x * x
pwr = lambda x, y: x ** y
for a in range(-2, 3):
    print(sqr(a), end=" ") 
    print(a,"**",two(),"=",pwr(a, two()))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "we all know?"  Why do you expect `-4` as an answer?  Negative 2 to the 2nd power is 4.

Comment: "We all know that -2 ** 2 = -4" Only because of precedence. `-2 ** 2` is `-(2 ** 2)`, which is indeed -4. But `(-2) ** 2` is 4 and that's what your lambda calculates when applied to the arguments `-2` and `2`.

Comment: @sepp2k You're correct, and the binding of Python's `**` operator is demonstrably confusing enough to warrant an explanation in an answer. For instance, the fact that `-2**2` is `-4` because `**` has higher precedence on the left, but simultaneously `2**-2` is valid and equal to `0.5` because the unary minus is on the right of `**`

Answer (score 0):

The `**` operator binds more tightly than the `-` operator does in Python. If you want to override that, you'd use parentheses, e.g. `(-i)**4`